# How to add Android StackExchange RSS feed to HTC news reader app

Tags: htc-desire, rss

I've been trying to add https://android.stackexchange.com/feeds to my RSS feeds in the News application on my HTC Desire Z. However it doesn't "find" any results. I just want to add this URL as it is instead of searching for it. Isn't this possible?

Comment: I was all set to add an answer along the lines of "it's really simple, you just...", and then realised I couldn't do it either! :)  I *do* have this site's RSS feed in my News app, but that's because I'm subscribed in Google Reader - maybe that's a workaround for you?  Interested to see if there is a 'proper' way though.

Comment: Glad that I'm not the only one. ;-) I tried the workaround, but whenever I access the Google Reader RSS feed it says "No Stories". :-(

Comment: did you have any luck fixing it?

Comment: @Daniel Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend another way of fetching RSS feeds to your cell phone:

1. Synchronize News Reader to your Google Account (to read news from Google Reader - it should be available there)
2. From your 'big' computer add this URL (http://android.stackexchange.com/feeds) to your subscription in Google Reader.
3. You should see news from Android.SE in your News Reader after its next sync with Google Reader.

Comment: How do I link my News Reader App with my Google account?

Comment: Ok got it, it's by default linked... that worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You may have already done all this but I will detail the steps I just took to add this to my HTC Evo.  It worked so maybe there is something different I'm doing.  First off I have never used the News app before.

1. Opened the News app
2. Deleted all default feeds
3. Clicked "Add Feed"
4. Clicked "Add from URL"
5. Entered in the URL you have above
6. Clicked "Done"
7. Feed Appeared with 30 unread.

Then to see if maybe you had typed the URL incorrectly on your device, I entered almost the exact same URL with one letter off and I got a warning that the feed was incorrect.  So since you didn't mention this I'm guessing thats not your issue.

If none of this helped - can you add any other feeds or its just the android.stackexchange feed that isn't working?

Comment: Tried it and there's no "Add from URL" button on my phone. After I click "Add Feed" there's a button "Search further" (in German) and then it says "Enter key word or feed URL for search". I did successfully add other URLs, but I think it only worked because they were found in the Google feed directory(?).

Comment: @werner5471 I wonder can you add other Stack Exchange sites? If so maybe when we are out of beta it will work.  I find it odd though that it would work on my HTC but not yours. Just a thought.

Comment: @werner5471 Not that I would expect it to change anything but have you tried this since we left beta?

Comment: I found a workaround for adding own URLs now, however it still doesn't work with Android Stackexchange. I opened the Android Stackexchange main page in the HTC's browser, then pushed the RSS button in the URL bar. Usually I can then add the given feed URL. However for Android Stackexchange it says "Wrong URL-format:/feeds" (in German).